# onclick ajax other all links enable

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I need to make all links enable during my ajax loading via jquery

http://frontier.rsitbs.com/frontier/main.php that is site when I onclcik the activities link 
until ajax load the contents all links disable I need to know how to enable all links as usual during ajax contents loading

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Surfing").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        $("#hide").show("slow");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "dynamic_activities.php",
            dataType: "html",
            data: "q=24",
            success: function(msg){
                function activateDatePicker() {
                    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
                }
                $("#txtHint").html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: please more information. For your information, these links do not work regardless of whether I go to the Activities link first or not. The following links do not work at all when tested in Safari browser: TOURS & SAFARIS

DESTINATIONS

VIDEOS

FORUM

Comment: looks like the error comes from the html part, set it on http://jsfiddle.net so we could have a look

Comment: Kuf can clcik activities menue then u get radio buttion which is combine with ajax I mean when u click radio button in the down contents change via ajax when u click activities button u will get radio groups by question is after click the radio or ajax link until ajax load the contents other all links will be disable I need to know why